# How to run Rodeo with python 2.7 on windows?

Tags: python-2.7, rodeo

I installed `python 2.7.14` then `Rodeo` for windows.

it seems my python installation was not useful because [doc says](http://rodeo.yhat.com/docs/#launching-rodeo) :

> For Windows users, there are no requirements, just download Rodeo!
>
> (Rodeo for Windows ships with a built-in conda environment)

However it seems Rodeo is running `Python 3`. as shown by it failing to execute `print "hello world"` but executing `print("hello world")` just fine.

I explored the settings and tried to set `Use built-in Python` to `No` with no success.

So how can I get `Rodeo` to run `Python 2.7` ?